# Set build number format in YAML pipelines

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines

I have a property group in my `.csproj` file with major, minor and patch version, which is to define the NuGet package version. It looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MajorVersionOfNuget>1</MajorVersionOfNuget>
    <MinorVersionOfNuget>1</MinorVersionOfNuget>
    <PatchVersionOfNuget>0</PatchVersionOfNuget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In our old Azure Pipelines (classic) these properties are used to set a *build number format*, under options. Like such:

[image: Screenshot from options in a classic Azure Pipeline]

How do I do this, in the YAML version of Azure Pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, you need to use the value in .csproj file to set the build number.

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, the value in .csproj file can not be used as Pipeline variable to set the build number directly.

To meet your requirement, you need to use script to get the value in csproj and then you can use logging command: [UpdateBuildNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number) to update the build number.

Here is a PowerShell example:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $xml = [Xml] (Get-Content $(build.sourcesdirectory)\xx.csproj(Filepath))
   $MajorVersionOfNuget=  $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.MajorVersionOfNuget
   $MinorVersionOfNuget=  $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.MinorVersionOfNuget
   $PatchVersionOfNuget=  $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.PatchVersionOfNuget
   
   echo $MajorVersionOfNuget
   
   echo $MinorVersionOfNuget
   
   echo $PatchVersionOfNuget
   
   echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$MajorVersionOfNuget.$MinorVersionOfNuget.$PatchVersionOfNuget"
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Comment: Where in the pipeline would this go, and what does `$(build.sourcesdirectory` refer to? I can't really get it to find the .csproj file.

Comment: You need to set the correct path of the csproj file in Get-Content command. The $(build.sourcesdirectory) is pipeline predefined variable.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml  it equals to source folder. for example: c:\agent_work\1\s . You need to modify the path based on your repo folder path

Comment: Now I got it to read the version, thanks. But how do I access it later in the pipeline then? I tried both `$MajorVersionOfNuget` and `$(MajorVersionOfNuget)`, without luck.

Comment: If you want to use it in next tasks , you need to set the value as Pipeline variable. Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline for example: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MajorVersionOfNuget;isOutput=true]$MajorVersionOfNuget"`

Answer (score 0):

You can customize how your pipeline runs are numbered. The default value for run number is $(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r).

In YAML, the build number is defined by the property called name and is at the root level of a pipeline. If not specified, your run is given a unique integer as its name.

```yaml
name: $(TeamProject)_$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

steps:
  - script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)' # outputs customized build number like project_def_master_20200828.1
```

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml))

Comment: I stumbled across this one in my search, but how do I get it to use the attributes from the `.csproj` file? The `<MajorNugetVersion>` and so on?